# React Native : using expo-av does not show Video but when I use the Inspector and select Touchables I can see the elements

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, react-devtools, expo-av

I have created an app using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` command and I have used the `expo-av` npm package with Video in the Background (occupying the entire screen) and some Images which can be clicked using `Touchable Opacity`. I am trying on iOS.

I migrated this code from expo to just react-native.  When I try to load the feed I can not see the Video or any elements on it but when I open the Inspector and select Touchables I am able to see all the elements on the screen.

I am not sure why this behaviour.

Did anyone face similar problem ?